# Why are my subscriptions no longer being delivered to my gmail account

Tags: support

For the last two weeks, my tag subscriptions are no longer being delivered to my gmail account. I have also noted that no confirmation messages are forwarded when I subscribe for new tags. What could be the cause?

Comment: Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: Yeah. Nothing under spam folder.

Comment: Same here, nothing in my spam folder.  Emails come at odd intervals or not at all.

Comment: Can confirm this works with non-gmail account.

Answer (score -11):

This could simply be Google's fault. I would subscribe maybe to the Stack Overflow newsletter you will receive it every Thursday. If this newsletter does not show up in your E-Mail try the google help center.