# Is it possible my account was deleted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, accounts

This may not be the right place for this question but I am not sure of where else to ask.

This is a follow up on [Why are my subscriptions no longer being delivered to my Gmail account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315945/why-are-my-subscriptions-no-longer-being-delivered-to-my-gmail-account)

After I was unable to get any answers to the question, I logged out and tried to log in again. Surprisingly, I was unable to log in again. I created another account with the same credentials and display name and everything works now.

Now I can't comment on or answer the question I asked.

Is it possible then that my account got deleted or lost in the wide web?

Comment: Given the user name on the question you link isn't greyed out, and we can still hit the profile, no, it doesn't look like the account was deleted. You should be able to merge this new account into your old one and get in that way, I would think.

Comment: Your account is still there, you're just not using the correct credential. You should [contact us](/contact) and we can assist you in getting the credentials merged.

Comment: The instructions to merge are [in the help center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) Alternatively, if you don't want to risk the merge yet, you can email the team through the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page and explain what's going on. They'll be able to help you sort it out, and might get to it faster that way. (Edit: Nvm, Animuson is on the team and proved me wrong.)

Comment: @animuson I have not changed any of my credentials. Mails for my previous account are not being forwarded to any of my email accounts and that was my original issue. I have already contacted for merging of the accounts but there is no way I can make a confirmation for the previous account as no mail is received.

Comment: @CallMeKags Please use the Other option and explain the situation if you don't have access to the other email address and we will provide instructions for you via email.

Comment: This is an active problem with Google login. S/O is a pain in the rear to sign on, I'm forced to clear cookies, login to Google account linked with S/O, login to S/O, _then_ log in to my work/spam Google accounts, every week or so.

Comment: @AaronGillion Hmm, I've been using a Google account for years and haven't experienced that. Are you using a Google Apps account for your Stack Overflow login? (I'm not.)

Comment: Not sure. All of mine have 2 step verification though

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Do you have multiple Google accounts? From Aaron's description, it sounds like that might be triggering the issue. (I might give it a try myself, since I happen to have a second Google account I created when I got my Android tablet. I don't normally use Google authentication for SO, though.)